# Python runtime for the code significantly different depending upon where the recursion function is placed

Tags: python, class, oop, recursion, caching

I am trying to solve a [leetcode problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-ways-to-rearrange-sticks-with-k-sticks-visible/). My solution gives markedly different results depending upon the kind of construction I have of the code. The only way to explain this is by giving you the three codes.

**Runtime: 3700ms**

```
class Solution:
    def rearrangeSticks(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:
        self.m = 10**9 + 7
        out = self.rs(n, k)
        return out
    @cache
    def rs(self,n, k):
        if k <= 0 :
            return 0
        if n < k:
            return 0
        if n == k:
            return 1
        out1 = self.rs(n-1, k-1)
        out2 = self.rs(n-1, k)

        out = (out1+out2*(n-1))%(self.m)
        return out
```

**Runtime: 1700ms**

```
class Solution:
    def rearrangeSticks(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:
        m = 10**9 + 7
        @cache
        def rs(n, k):
            if k <= 0 :
                return 0
            if n < k:
                return 0
            if n == k:
                return 1
            out1 = rs(n-1, k-1)
            out2 = rs(n-1, k)

            out = (out1+out2*(n-1))%(m)
            return out
        out = rs(n, k)
        return out
```

**Runtime: 200ms**

```
class Solution:
    def rearrangeSticks(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:
        out = rs(n, k)
        return out
m = 10**9 + 7
@cache
def rs(n, k):
    if k <= 0 :
        return 0
    if n < k:
        return 0
    if n == k:
        return 1
    out1 = rs(n-1, k-1)
    out2 = rs(n-1, k)
    out = (out1+out2*(n-1))%(m)
    return out
```

Can you help me understand why the 3 runtimes so different?

Comment: We'd also need how you are actually calling each of those codes.

Comment: But the immediate problem I see is that only last one makes correct use of cache, because the function is global and not inner/method of an object.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. If I remove caching from any of these the solution times out. I am not sure how leet code calls the solution though :/

Comment: the cache does speed things up in all cases. But only in the last one it does it's job as it should.

Comment: I see the point though. I think the last case is so fast because it is able to use caching across examples and in this problem the solutions for the subproblems would incidentally be the same across the examples. I am not sure why the first one is so slow though. There also I think the cache would be reused